# Почему не отображаются элементы раскрывающегося списка?

Tags: php, html, mysql

Я пытаюсь заполнить раскрывающийся список из БД MySQL. Соединение с базой проходит, выбор базы тоже. Запрос вроде тоже проходит нормально. Селектор отображается, а элементы нет. Но почему то не отображаются элементы списка. Не могу понять в чем проблема, то ли в запросе дело, или в html коде внутри php. Пробовал и php внутри html тега option прописывать. Помогите разобраться в чем проблема.

```
<?php require_once('connect.php')?>
<div>
<select>
    <?php
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM department";
        $result = mysqli_query($sql) or die('Запрос не удался: ' . mysql_error());

        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {

            echo '<option value="' . $row['id'] . '">' . $row['department'] . '</option>';
        }
    ?>
</select>
</div>
```

Вот connect.php

```
<?php
$connection = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '') or die('Не удалось соединиться: ' . mysql_error());

echo "Соединение успешно установлено";

$select_db = mysqli_select_db($connection, 'support') or die('Не удалось выбрать базу данных: ' . mysql_error());
?>
```

Comment: `mysqli_query($sql)` не указано соединение. `mysql_error()` серьезно? mysql и mysqli - разные вещи

Comment: Пробовал указывать соединение. Не помогает.